# How can I apply hover effects to a Z-index applied div?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<title>HOver</title>
<style>
    .1 { 
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        hieght:100;
        width:100;
    }
    .2 { 
        position:relative;
        top:0;
        Z-index:9999;
        hieght:100;
        width:100;
        background-color:white;
    }
    .2:hover {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="1">fdigiuguisagcuiagi</div>
<div class="2">cuoisgdcahouio</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hover is not working in this code. If I remove the `Z-index`, the hover is working.

How can I apply the hover for this code?

Comment: Try change your classes to letters instead of numbers, so you could say .one and .two

Comment: number classes does not work

Comment: use javascript, onmouse enter, since mouseover  wont work for the element  that is behind or lower with the element with z-index higher layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Now again

```css
.first { 
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        height:100;
        width:100;
        color:blue;
        z-index:99999;
    }
    .second { 
        position:relative;
        top:25px;
        z-index:9999;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    .third { 
        position:relative;
        top:50px;
        z-index:9999;
        height:500px;
        width:500px;
        background-color:green;
    }
    .second:hover,.third:hover {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }
```

```html
<div class="first">fdigiuguisagcuiagi</div>
<div class="second">cuoisgdcahouio</div>
<div class="third">cuoisgdcahouio</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for Your response. but here we are having only 2 div's . when we  are creating a website if we set header is fixed, at that time we have to apply z-index to all other div's. In that case hover is not applied to the remaining div's.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rxkf456n/ check this fiddle you can remove z-index to others div and its work

Answer (score 1):

Correct your errors and the code will work:

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HOver</title>
<style>
    /*error class name should not start with a digit*/
    .div-1 { 
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        height:100px;/*misspelling - hieght*/
        width:100px;/*you must specify the measurement unit px, %, em, rem, vh, vw*/
    }
    .div-2 { 
        position:relative;
        top:0;
        /*Z-index:9999;*/
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        background-color:white;
    }
    .div-2:hover {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div-1">fdigiuguisagcuiagi</div>
<div class="div-2">cuoisgdcahouio</div>
</body>
</html>
```